# Knowing the number of bits to represent a number

Tags: algorithm

I learn that in order to determine the number of bits needed to represent a number *n* is by taking the logarithm of n, i.e. *`log(n)`* (base 2). However, I am not convinced! Look at my example:

if `n=4`, then I need `log4 = 2 bits` to represent 4, but 4 is (100) in binary which is clearly 3 bits!!

Can someone explain why?
Thank you.

Comment: downvote! Is there something wrong? I am sorry in advance

Comment: Yes I can explain it! What you have learned is *wrong*. Unlearn it now. With `k` bits you can represent numbers from `0` to `2^k-1`. Alas, `2^k` is outside of this range. Perhaps you want to learn that you need exactly `log(n)` bits to represent every natural number *less than `n`*. To include `n` you *might* need another bit.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you very much. Very clear now. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you aren't talking about n bit arrangements ?

With 2 bits you have 4 different sequences:

```
00
01
10
11
```

The number 4 is effectively 100 in binary, but I'm suspecting that you mixed those concepts.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No I am not talking about arrangement because I know I need n factorial for that. I just learned this from youtube lesson that (in order to determine the number of bits needed to represent a number n is by taking the logarithm) so I am trying to convince myself! I think I am mixing something here. Thank you

Comment: As @n.m. commented on your question, _do not try to convince yourself_ since that is not right. `log(n)` will either give you, like I said, the number of bit arrangements, or like n.m. mentionned, the number of bits to represent integers Smaller than `n`.

Comment: Thank you Mat for clarification .

Answer (score 1):

To most direct scheme, you take `ceil(log2(N+1))` with `log2` expressed as floating.

In pure integral, a naive scheme would be to divide (integral div, thus trunc) the number by 2 until you get a result of zero (e.g. 4/2=2, 2/2=1, 1/2=0 - three divisions to go to zero, thus 3 bits are needed).

More [advanced schemes exist](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog), but going that path may hurt you performance - modern CPU-es have [instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) to detect the position of the msb set to 1 for a number, instructions which require very few CPU cycles.

Comment: Actually it's `ceil(log2(N+1))`, that's where OP got it wrong.